# Use SendKeys with string in c#?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

i have been using SendKeys.SendWait("insert letter here"); to send a letter to an all ready focused application. This works fine. I have aldo been using it like SendKeys.SendWait(letterstosend); to send a string with only letters in. I notice however it wont send a tring that has both letters and numbers in. It focuses the application but sends nothing.

Can anyone advise on how to write a loop to read the first letter in a string and then send it with the SendKeys.SendWait command and then read the second letter and send that etc for thw whole string?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

SendKeys should definitely handle multiple letters well, however, if you want to send each character you can solve it like this:

```
string text = "abc123";
foreach(char c in text)
    SendKeys.SendWait(c.ToString());
```

Note that there are several special characters in SendKeys that you might have to escape for this to work properly. [More info on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28VS.90%29.aspx)

This might also have been the problem why your original approach failed.